# how to define multiple npm peerDependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies

I have created a Phaser plugin and I'm not sure how to correctly define peerDependencies for it. The problem is that phaser has recently been copied and moved to a new repo 'phaser-ce'. The plugin depends on either 'phaser@2.x' or 'phaser-ce@2.x'.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "phaser": "2.x" || "phaser-ce": "2.x"
```

Obviously that doesn't work...is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "phaser": "2.x",
    "phaser-ce": "2.x"}
```

You use double pipe when you need different versions of same package like:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "phaser": "2.x || 3.x",
    "phaser-ce": "2.x"}
```

Comment: but that suggests that both phaser AND phaser-ce are deps. Whereas my app depends on either phaser OR phaser-ce

Comment: Or ? How will your app do that decision ?

Comment: you will `import Phaser from 'phaser'` or `import Phaser from 'phaser-ce`. They are the same code-base but the repo was split.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of (almost) 2024, it's not possible to define either of the two packages as your peer dependency.

Your best bet is to add both to your `peerDependencies`[[1]](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) and `peerDependenciesMeta`[[2]](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependenciesmeta) package.json's properties like @Doruk suggested

```json
{
    "peerDependencies": {
        "phaser": "2.x",
        "phaser-ce": "2.x"
    },
    "peerDependenciesMeta": {
        "phaser": {
            "optional": true
        },
        "phaser-ce": {
            "optional": true
        }
  }
}
```

and include some additional information on it in your `README`

```markdown
## Installation

To use this library, you need to have either `phaser` or `phaser-ce` package installed in your project
```

*or*

Just don't include them in package.json at all and stick to the `README` plus some runtime checking.